# setFunction of useState won't change OnClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this useState element, but the function doesn't get called onClick.
I have tried many solutions and debugging and it seems like the Click event doesn't get called, no matter what.

`const [modalHotel, setModalHotel] = useState(false)`

`{modalHotel && <ModalHotel CloseModal = {setModalHotel} />}`

`<img src="./assets/square.svg" alt="expand" onClick={() => setModalHotel(!modalHotel)}/>`

Comment: What is it meant to do? How is that change meant to be reflected in your component when it re-renders? There's no enough code to go on here.

Comment: @Andy When the img is clicked the state will turn true thus rendering a component ```{modalHotel && <ModalHotel CloseModal = {setModalHotel} />}```

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) which help you try and explain more about your code by updating your question.

Comment: Have you tried just logging something and see if that changes? e.g.

`onClick={() => console.log('it it working')}`. this is to just check if the error is not from the `ModalHotel` component.

Comment: I don't like when questions don't give enough information to even reproduce the issue.  I'm voting to close as not reproducible -- especially in lieu of the self-confessed css-related actual cause which was not disclosed in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

I had this `z-index: -1;` in my css, removed it and it worked.

Comment: that'd do it! sounded very much like it was a CSS issue if even buttons weren't working :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes elements won't register `onClick` events in React unless you specify a `tabIndex`. Try this:

```
const checkClick = () => {
  console.log("It worked!!");
  setModalHotel(!modalHotel);
}

<img tabIndex={0} src="./assets/square.svg" alt="expand" onClick={checkClick} />
```

this will help you to debug whether the click event is actually being fired.

#### Side Note:

From an accessibility perspective, it's almost always preferrable to use either `button` or `a` elements to handle clicks like this. They have tabIndexes by default, and better a11y support in general.

Comment: Nothing was console logged, even with tabindex{0}. Tried changing img to button but nothing. It's almost like the 'onClick' event is invisible.

Comment: Did you use `tabIndex={0}` with correct capitalization? Does a button placed elsewhere on the page trigger an `onClick` event?

Comment: The problem was from CSS ```z-index: -1;```. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough information to completely diagnose your issue.  But in the meantime, here is a working snippet with an element that is clickable (a button) to toggle state using a `useState` hook.  You can compare what is different between your non-working code and this working example.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Thing = (props) => {
  const [modalHotel, setModalHotel] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{modalHotel.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setModalHotel(!modalHotel)}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Thing />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```